# Reading a .csv file with multiple duplicate words and rewriting each word once

Tags: python, csv, collections, functools

I have a database with .csv files. I want to read them, and find out how many different words each contain. For each one I want to write a new .csv file with these words.

This is  an example of my data:

```
Praske -OK
1

Praske -OK,Koda
1,1

Praske -OK,Koda,Referenca
1,1,1
```

And I want my output file to be:

```
Praske -OK,Koda,Referenca
```

I believe something like that can be achieved with `collections` and `functools` libraries. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I'm not sure what those 1,1,1 are… Input data in the same csv ? Output data per input csv ?

Comment: So you want to ignore numeric data? You need to be much clearer about what the input is and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set`.

For each word in your csv file, add them to a set
Then you can write all element of the set in a new file.

Something like this

```py
words = set()
for word in document:
  words.add(word)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
  print(*words, sep=',', file=f) # create a csv file from the set
```